# concurrent for loop over 2 variables

Tags: matlab, for-loop, octave

Is it possible in Octave to made 2 loops in the same time like :

```
(for i=0:10 && j=10:20)
  i;
  j;
  end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the loops are of the same length, then yes. Not well known is that for non-vectors, a for loop, loops over columns.  So just place your vectors in a matrix, one row per variable:

```
for r = [0:10; 10:20]
  printf ("1st is %2i; 2nd is %2i\n", r(1), r(2));
endfor
```

which returns:

```
1st is  0; 2nd is 10
1st is  1; 2nd is 11
1st is  2; 2nd is 12
1st is  3; 2nd is 13
1st is  4; 2nd is 14
1st is  5; 2nd is 15
1st is  6; 2nd is 16
1st is  7; 2nd is 17
1st is  8; 2nd is 18
1st is  9; 2nd is 19
1st is 10; 2nd is 20
```

Answer (score 2):

In Matlab you can use [`arrayfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html) with two input arrays of the same size:

```
>> arrayfun(@(x,y) x+y, 1:10, 10:10:100)
ans =
    11    22    33    44    55    66    77    88    99   110
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to move in step then use a counter variable to reference them as arrays:

```
j = 0:10;
i = 0:10;
for k = 1:11
    i(k);
    j(k);
end
```

But you most likely need to make nested for loops:

```
for i = 0:10
    for j = 0:10
        i;
        j;
    end
end
```